# How can I show a spinner during a long JavaScript execution?

Tags: javascript

I have been playing with this for a long time now and cannot get a spinner in CSS to show when I press a button and then hide after the JavaScript function execution. This is a snippet of what I am attempting to do with pure JavaScript.

```
<button id="spinBtn" onclick="spinIt()">Spin it</button>
<div class="spinner" style="visibility:hidden;">

<script>
function spinIt() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("spinner").style.visibility = "visible";
    setTimeout(function () {
        // long code here
        document.getElementsByClassName("spinner").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }, 1); // give it a moment to redraw
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/imparante/h9kLL1se/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

Instead of `document.getElementsByClassName` ,  use `document.querySelectorAll` and increase the setTimeout time interval.

And `document.getElementsByClassName` return array of match element. To pick the first element, use `document.getElementsByClassName('spinner')[0]`

```js
function spinIt() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".spinner")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
  setTimeout(function() {
    // long code here
    document.querySelectorAll(".spinner")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
  }, 1000); // give it a moment to redraw
}
```

```css
.spinner {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.container1 > div,
.container2 > div,
.container3 > div {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: bouncedelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: bouncedelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  /* Prevent first frame from flickering when animation starts */
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.spinner .spinner-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.container2 {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}
.container3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  transform: rotateZ(90deg);
}
.circle1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.circle2 {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.circle3 {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.circle4 {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.container2 .circle1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
}
.container3 .circle1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
  animation-delay: -1.0s;
}
.container1 .circle2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
}
.container2 .circle2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
  animation-delay: -0.8s;
}
.container3 .circle2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.7s;
  animation-delay: -0.7s;
}
.container1 .circle3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.6s;
  animation-delay: -0.6s;
}
.container2 .circle3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.5s;
  animation-delay: -0.5s;
}
.container3 .circle3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.4s;
  animation-delay: -0.4s;
}
.container1 .circle4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.3s;
  animation-delay: -0.3s;
}
.container2 .circle4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.2s;
  animation-delay: -0.2s;
}
.container3 .circle4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.1s;
  animation-delay: -0.1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bouncedelay {
  0%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.0)
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0)
  }
}
@keyframes bouncedelay {
  0%, 80%, 100% {
    transform: scale(0.0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.0);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button id="comboBtn" onclick="spinIt()">Combo it</button>
</p>

<div class="spinner" style="visibility:hidden">
  <div class="spinner-container container1">
    <div class="circle1"></div>
    <div class="circle2"></div>
    <div class="circle3"></div>
    <div class="circle4"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="spinner-container container2">
    <div class="circle1"></div>
    <div class="circle2"></div>
    <div class="circle3"></div>
    <div class="circle4"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="spinner-container container3">
    <div class="circle1"></div>
    <div class="circle2"></div>
    <div class="circle3"></div>
    <div class="circle4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns *many elements* (plural). At the very least you'd have to do this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("spinner")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
                                          ^^^
```

Though you should either loop through this element list and make *all* spinners visible, or you should use a unique `id` for your spinner and get this one specific spinner via `document.getElementById` (singular).